# Drupal 9 Views: rich text fields render with all HTML tags visible

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, civicrm-entity, textarea

HTML tags added by CiviCRM's rich text editor is generated as plain text in Views output for fields like CiviEvent description or custom rich text fields. Stripping tags in the Views output doesn't tidy it up:

[image: image of html output]

Answer (score 4):

Based on feedback from Skvare's Mark Hanna on [chat.civicrm.org](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/hups56ac77gyjrge83193eawda) you need to rewrite the field output, using the `_value` version and add `|raw` in the twig.

For the event description field, this looks like: `{{ description__value__value|raw }}`.